# Opening the file in vs window

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This window always starts when I double-click the project file or any file with extension .addin.

I unistalled and installed it again, updated to the last VS 17.8.4.

This is the window that showed for me each time:

[image]

I tried everything.

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. If it was helpful to you, please mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people. If it doesn't work for you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation in Visual Studio 2013. You need to close Visual Studio and delete all *.csproj.user files in the project to return to normal.

But I noticed in the lower left corner of your screenshot: "invalid copilot token: missing token: 404". Please refer to: [visual studio: "invalid copilot token: missing token: 404"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765315/visual-studio-invalid-copilot-token-missing-token-404)

Comment: i deleted the .csproj.user but nothing changed

Comment: @AhmedSherif Have you tried the method in the link? Does it work for you?

Comment: no nothing changed